# All triangles are equilateral

Tags: geometry

So I was watching a video in which a man has "proven" that all triangles are equilateral. He also said that there is somewhere an error but I really cant find. So can someone show me it or give me a hint.

The video:
http://youtu.be/Yajonhixy4g

What I noticed is that if AB=AC then AX and AM are the same line and cant intersect.

Comment: There are two perpendiculars, $XB^*$ and $XC^*$, he draws that must fall one inside the triangle and another outside, instead of both outside or both inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @G-man, Lewis Caroll's fallacy can be found in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy

It includes 2 tricks:-

(1) O is inside the triangle.

(2) Both perpendiculars from O to the sides AB and AC are inside the ⊿ABC. (As pointed out by @Pp…)

The explanation in Wiki’s tempts to include both of the above in one shot. This could possibly mislead some to think that both conditions are needed together to yield the fallacy. The video successfully demonstrates that the fallacy depending on (2) alone.

Maybe it is time for Wiki to amend its content – a little suggestion.